# I have an array, and have to destroy the elements of array one by one. I have an O(n^2) solution. Can someone help in optimizing it a bit

Tags: python, arrays, permutation

I have an array 'a' and. I have to destroy elements of array one by one.The order in we destroy the elements is given by the permutation 'p' such that in the ith iteration we destroy a[p[i]].
After destroying the elements we have to find the segment of array such that it contains no element destroyed and has the maximum sum.

```
a=[9865,9838,9986,9915,9844,9957,9946,9819,9964,9919]
p=[8,0,7,4,6,2,3,9,1,5]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[p[i]]=-1
    maxi=0
    left=0
    while left<len(a):
        while left<len(a) and a[left]==-1:
            left+=1
        right=left
        x=0
        while(right<len(a) and a[right]!=-1):
            x+=a[right]
            right+=1
        maxi=max(x,maxi)
        left=right+1
    print(maxi)
```

output will be --> 79170 69305 59486 29739 29739 9957 9957 9957 9957 0

I am having this solution which runs in O(n^2) complexity. Can we do it in less than that?

Comment: *"I'm having this solution"*: I don't think it is valid. It calculates a sum over a range that might still include a value that might later be destroyed. I would think you should only look for these sums *after* all destructions have been peformed.

Comment: Also, you write that *"we have to find the segment of array such that it contains no element destroyed and has the maximum sum"*, but then your solution outputs *several* sums, and no *segment*. I'm confused... what exactly is the expected output?

Comment: @trincot since `p` contains all the indices, there is nothing left in the original list after all destructions have been performed. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: for example : value of p[0] is 8 so it means we have to destroy 8th element from the array 'a'. After destroying (in my code i have marked it as -1, since array does not contain negative elements) there are two segments created 1. [0,7] and 2. [9,9] where 0,7 and 9 are indexes of array 'a'. Sum of these segments is 79170 and 9919. Out of both 79170 is maximum, hence the output.

Comment: @mark no you are absolutely correct, that is why the last output is 0.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSINGH, then why would you continue to search for a maximum when your input values are all positive? Certainly adding another -1 *cannot* give you a sum that is *greater* than you already had after processing the first -1. Can you clarify?

Comment: @trincot -1 is just to denote that, that particular element was deleted or destroyed. Since I cannot remove element from list that is why I am marking it as -1.

Comment: I understand that, but that is not my doubt. Is the purpose to output an overall largest sum, and **one** segment, or as *many* outputs as there are elements in `p`? Each time outputting the range and the corresponding sum?

Comment: Your question has *"... we have to find **the** segment..."*, but now I am thinking it is not **the** segment, but many segments...

Comment: @trincot lets take smaller input size. a=[3,2,1] and p=[1,2,0].  In this example we destroy a[p[0]] which '2' from array 'a'. So, the segments which are created are [0,0] and [2,2] out of that 3 is maximum. So the output for this example will be [3,3,0]

Comment: @trincot out of all the segments which will be created we have to find out maximum sum segment.

Comment: I am confused by the **singular** in your last phrase. Did you mean *"we have to find out maximum sum segments"*? (plural). Also, it seems you want *sums*, not *segments* in your output.

Comment: @trincot ok lets take the index=3 from the array 'p' it has the value 4. It means that before coming the that index 8,0,7 have already created segments in the array. These segments will be from ( [1,6] and [9,9] created by 7), ( [0,7] and [9,9] created by 8) ,( [1,7] created by 0) and ([1,3], [5,6] and [9,9] created by 4).

Comment: @trincot these segments are to be created such that they must not include the destroyed element.

Comment: Creation of segments seems to be an implementation aspect. Can you confirm that the output does not consist of segments, but of sums, and as many as there are values in `p`?

Comment: *"all possible segments for that particular element"*: are there more than 2 created by a single element? I'd think there is only the segment created at the left and right of the destroyed element? Which other segments should be considered? Anyway, I  am giving up. Hope someone else will help you out.

Comment: @trincot for value of 4. There will be 3 segments ([1,3] ,[5,6] and [9,9])